# Combine graphicspath and import

Tags: svg, import

I would like to use the `import` package to specify my image location by using the `graphicspath` command. So instead of

```
\begin{figure}[H]
 \begin{center}
 \def\svgwidth{\textwidth} 
 \import{/path/to/figure/}{image.pdf_tex} 
 \end{center}  
\end{figure}
```

I would like to use it (if possible) something like

```
\graphicspath{{/path/to/figure/}}

\begin{figure}[H]
 \begin{center}
 \def\svgwidth{\textwidth} 
 \import{}{image.pdf_tex} 
 \end{center}  
\end{figure}
```

How can this be done?

Comment: `\graphicspath`  is defined by the standard graphics package you do not need import package for that.

Comment: But I believe that I do need the `import` or an `input` to work with `image.pdf_tex` files produced by inkscape.

Comment: personally I'd just use `\input` and put inkskape's tex and pdf file in a directory in your TEXINPUTS path, then all you need is `\input{image.pdf_tex}`

Comment: thx for pointing me to TEXINPUTS. I tested the approach using the IDE kile. I have multiple projects with a figures folder each. using TEXINPUTS does not search subfolders so I have to provide multiple paths and maintain some data outside of my projects. this does not really solve the issue.